# How to round to the nearest upper 15 minutes in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Using moment.js, I want to round to the nearest 15 minutes but from now on. For example:

`10:13am -> 10:15am
 11:01am -> 11:15am`

Comment: 11:15 pm or am?

Comment: Are you asking how to round a number to a nearest 15?

Comment: I want to round to the nearest 15 but from now on, not before

Comment: I think he means, to round it UP, instead of rounding it DOWN.

Comment: You need something like this `date.setMinutes(Math.ceil(date.getMinutes()/15)*15); date.setSeconds(0);` Just check edge cases.

Comment: I need it with moment.js

Comment: I bet there is module adding `setNearestHourQuarter` for your convenience ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This might help you.This uses momentjs

```
var moment = require("moment");
const start = moment("2018-12-08 09:42");
const remainder = 15 - (start.minute() % 15);
const dateTime = moment(start)
  .add(remainder, "minutes")
  .format("DD.MM.YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
console.log(dateTime);
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-bas-fg1c2

Comment: You do not have to add the remainder if the time was already a multiple of 15.

Comment: That returns 10:41:00. I need it 09:45

Comment: @YovchoKalev Check the sandbox, it is returning 9:45 in the console

Comment: @YovchoKalev Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

That code below is made with this: https://momentjs.com/. I don't even know java script (sorry for the formatting). If I can do it, you can do it to.

```js
var thismoment = moment();
var now = thismoment.format('MMM DD h:mm A');
var minutes = thismoment.format('mm');
var rest = minutes % 15;
if (rest < 8) {
    alert(thismoment.subtract(rest, 'minutes').calendar());
} else {
    alert(thismoment.add(15 - rest, 'minutes').calendar());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```